# Category page main query load too much when it has hundreds of sub category in wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have main category **"Albums"** and all the **Album_Names** as sub category.

When I try to open category-albums.php page or say Album category page its take too much load.

**Below query fired.**

```
SELECT  wp_posts.ID
    FROM  wp_posts
    LEFT JOIN  wp_term_relationships
       ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
    WHERE  1=1
      AND  ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (4,5,6,
                7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,....,5000)  )
      AND  wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
      AND  (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
    GROUP BY  wp_posts.ID
    ORDER BY  wp_posts.post_date DESC
    LIMIT  0, 30
```

1. How to optimize this query? I don't want to show any post in page.
2. I want to show only child category list by name instead of post.

Comment: "I didn't watch to show any post in page." -- Please elaborate.  "show only child category list by name instead of post" -- please elaborate.

Comment: My wordpress structure are:
"Album" -> Main Category,
Album_names -> Child category,
Songs -> Post type, Album_name selected in post

I want to show All Albums Names in Album category page. Not songs.

Answer (score 0):

Some optimization tips

```
SELECT  wp_posts.ID
    FROM  wp_posts
    -- LEFT   -- probably misleading
    JOIN  wp_term_relationships
       ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
    WHERE  
    -- 1=1 AND  -- junk
           ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (4,5,6,
                7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,....,5000)  )
    -- Could that changed to be   "BETWEEN 4 and 5000"  ?
      AND  wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
      AND  (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
    GROUP BY  wp_posts.ID
    ORDER BY  wp_posts.ID DESC  -- same(?) effect, much better optimization
    LIMIT  0, 30
```

Indexes:

```
wp_posts:  (post_type, post_status, ID)
wp_term_relationships:  (object_id, term_taxonomy_id)
```

Comment: wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (4,5,...) are not in sequence. Its may be (5,8,10,16,20... ) etc

Both table has aleady indexed.

Comment: @Manish - OK, ignore the "range" suggestion.  Do you have those multi-column indexes?  They are better (for this query) than single-column indexes.

Comment: Yes, object_id and term_taxonomy_id are used as composite primary key.